# Updating existing activity with attachments

Tags: acumatica

I need to update an attachment to an existing activity using Web API from my application to an existing case in Acumatica Partner's Portal.

I have already written a code to this but it is updating to first activity always instead of for the activity I am passing the noteid.

I am doing this by retrieving the noteid of the activity created and then sending the same noteid along with caseid to update an attachment.

Below is the code which is updating the existing activity with attachment, please suggest.

```html
var origActivities = context1.Export
 (
  new SP203010WS.Command[]
  {
    new SP203010WS.Value
    {
     Value = currentAcumaticaCaseNo,
     LinkedCommand = content.Case.CaseID
    },

    content.Activities.Type,
    content.Activities.Summary,
    new SP203010WS.Field
    {
     FieldName = "NoteID",
     ObjectName = content.Activities.Summary.ObjectName
    },
    content.Activities.CreatedAt,
  },
  null, 0, false, false
 );

Guid?[] origActivityNoteID = null;
DateTime?[] origActivityCreatedDate = null;
if (origActivities != null && origActivities.Count() > 0)
{
 origActivityNoteID = new Guid?[origActivities.Count()];
 origActivityCreatedDate = new DateTime?[origActivities.Count()];

 int i = 0;
 foreach (string[] activity in origActivities)
 {
  origActivityNoteID[i] = new Guid(activity[2].ToString());
  origActivityCreatedDate[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(activity[3]);
  i++;
 }
}

*****Adding new activity*****

var newActivities = context.Export
 (
  new SP203010WS.Command[]
  {
    new SP203010WS.Value
    {
     Value = currentAcumaticaCaseNo,
     LinkedCommand = content.Case.CaseID
    },

    content.Activities.Type,
    content.Activities.Summary,
    new SP203010WS.Field
    {
     FieldName = "NoteID",
     ObjectName = content.Activities.Summary.ObjectName
    },
    content.Activities.CreatedAt,
  },
  null, 0, false, false
 );

Guid? newActivityNoteID = null;

for (var i = 1; i <= newActivities.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
 if(origActivityNoteID != null && origActivityCreatedDate != null)
 {
  if((Array.IndexOf<Guid?>(origActivityNoteID, new Guid(newActivities[i][2])) <= 0) &&
    (Array.IndexOf<DateTime?>(origActivityCreatedDate, Convert.ToDateTime(newActivities[i][3])) <= 0))
  {
   newActivityNoteID = new Guid(newActivities[i][2]);
   break;
  }
 }
}

*****getting a list of all attachments*****

foreach (FileInfo fi in fileInfo)
{
 SP203010WS.Content[] content1 = context.Submit
 (
  new SP203010WS.Command[]
   {
    new SP203010WS.Value
    {
     //Value = actiPartner.AcumaticaCaseID,
     Value = currentAcumaticaCaseNo,
     LinkedCommand = CR306000.Case.CaseID
    },
    new SP203010WS.Value
    {
     Value = newActivityNoteID.ToString(),
     LinkedCommand = new SP203010WS.Field { FieldName="NoteID", ObjectName="Activities" }
    },
    new SP203010WS.Value
    {
     FieldName = fi.Name,
     Value = Convert.ToBase64String(fi.BinData),
     LinkedCommand = CR306000.Activities.ServiceCommands.Attachment
    },
    CR306000.Actions.Save
   }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks  like search in Screen-Based API has no support for GUIDs. You will have to locate necessary Attachment by other fields values, for instance: Type, Summary and CreatedAt:

```
Screen context = new Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.Url = "http://localhost/ActivityAttachments/Soap/CR306000.asmx";
context.Login("admin", "123");

var content = context.GetSchema();

var newActivities = context.Export
(
    new Command[]
    {
            new Value
            {
                Value = "000110",
                LinkedCommand = content.CaseSummary.CaseID
            },

            content.Activities.Type,
            content.Activities.Summary,
            content.Activities.CreatedAt,
    },
    null, 0, false, false
);

byte[] filedata;
using (FileStream file = File.Open("EP507011.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    filedata = new byte[file.Length];
    file.Read(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);
}

Content[] content1 = context.Submit
(
    new Command[]
    {
        new Value
        {
            Value = "000110",
            LinkedCommand = content.CaseSummary.CaseID
        },
        new Key
        {
            ObjectName = content.Activities.Type.ObjectName,
            FieldName = content.Activities.Type.FieldName,
            Value = string.Format("='{0}'", newActivities[newActivities.Length - 2][0])
        },
        new Key
        {
            ObjectName = content.Activities.Summary.ObjectName,
            FieldName = content.Activities.Summary.FieldName,
            Value = string.Format("='{0}'", newActivities[newActivities.Length - 2][1])
        },
        new Key
        {
            ObjectName = content.Activities.CreatedAt.ObjectName,
            FieldName = content.Activities.CreatedAt.FieldName,
            Value = newActivities[newActivities.Length - 2][2]
        },
        new Value
        {
            FieldName = "EP507011.txt",
            Value = Convert.ToBase64String(filedata),
            LinkedCommand = content.Activities.ServiceCommands.Attachment
        },
        content.Actions.Save
    }
);
```

Comment: Still not working and its updating the first activity.

Comment: Can you please explain why you are mixing classes from SP203010WS and CR306000 namespaces? Not sure how this is supposed to work...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. CR306000 is nothing but an object name. It is already working but going to wrong activity. Here is the code for your reference

SP203010WS.Screen context = new SP203010WS.Screen();
context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
context.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
context.EnableDecompression = true;
context.Timeout = 1000000;

context.Url = "https://sso.acumatica.com/Soap/SP203010.asmx";

SP203010WS.LoginResult result = context.Login(username, password);

SP203010WS.Content CR306000 = context.GetSchema();

Comment: Updated my answer above

Comment: I see you are updating it with CreatedAt instead of NoteID. Wouldn't NoteId is the key field in table, why it is not updating the attachments with NoteId and instead it is updating with CreatedAt.

Comment: Search in Screen-Based API has no support for GUIDs (NoteID field is of the GUID type). You will have to locate necessary Activity using other fields, for instance: Type, Summary and CreatedAt

Comment: Ok Ruslan. Thank you.